# Service credentials are not populated when service instance is created using cloud foundry rest API

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, message-hub

I'm creating a Message Hub service instance using a python cloud foundry client:

```
$ pip install --user --quiet protobuf
$ pip install --user --quiet cloudfoundry-client

from cloudfoundry_client.client import CloudFoundryClient
target_endpoint = 'https://api.ng.bluemix.net'

client = CloudFoundryClient(target_endpoint, skip_verification=False)
client.init_with_user_credentials(
    ibm_id,
    ibm_id_password
    )

mh_service = client.service_instances.create(
    space_guid, 
    'my_mh2', 
    mh_plan_id
)
```

The service is created, but when I view the credentials using the management console, they are empty:

[image]

I've seen in the integration test code for the python client that parameters and tags can be created:

```
client.service_instances.create(
   'space_guid', 
   'name', 
   'plan_id',
   parameters=dict(the_service_broker="wants this object"),
   tags=['example']
)
```

Therefore, I'm guessing I need to pass something extra to tell bluemix to create some default credentials for me?

Comment: I just checked by creating a MessageHub instance from the bluemix UI and service credentials were created automatically, so how do I get the same behaviour from the API?

Comment: When I instantiate a service instance using `cf create-service messagehub standard messagehub` credentials don't get created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd need to raise another GH issue against that 3rd party Python client for CF to also allow creation of service keys https://github.com/antechrestos/cf-python-client/issues/11

Using the cf cli you'd do this:

```
cf create-service ${MESSAGE_HUB_SERVICE} ${MESSAGE_HUB_PLAN} ${MESSAGE_HUB_INSTANCE_NAME}
cf create-service-key ${MESSAGE_HUB_INSTANCE_NAME} Credentials-1
```